# Client not recieving message from server instead recieving null in java

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to learn network programming in java so far i have written 2 codes, one for client side, one for server side. First i run serverCode and then i run client code however client is recieving null on its end.

Server Side code:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *
 * @author saksham
 */
public class Chatserver {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(6966);
        while (true){
            Socket request=serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(request.getOutputStream());
           // InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream());
            //BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(ir);
            //String msg=bf.readLine();
            pw.println("you sent me the message:");
            request.close();


        }

    }

}
```

Client side code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author saksham
 */
public class Chat {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Socket socket=new Socket("127.0.0.1",6966);
       // PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        //System.out.println("\nEnter a message:->");
        //Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        //pw.println(sc.next());
        InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ir);
        String rcvd=br.readLine();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println(rcvd);
        rcvd=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(rcvd);


    }

}
```

I am very much aware i am not using a good coding style its just a test code since i am focussing on learning for now.

Comment: You might not want to close the socket before you are done reading from it.

Comment: atleast one message should have been printed right?

Comment: You need to close, or at least flush, the PrintWriter in class ChatServer before closing the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have closed `pw`, not the socket. At present your output is still buffered in the `PrintWriter`, and never gets sent at all.

When you've fixed that:

1. You are sending one line and then closing the socket.
2. You are reading two lines. The first `readLine()` will return the line you sent. The second `readLine()` will return null, indicating end of stream.

Comment: I added two lines of code as you mentioned they are
pw.flush()
pw.close() before closing the socket stil I am getting null two times while it should be null only once


But when i removed the line that closes socket, problem got solved any explainations for that?

Comment: You didn't do what I said, or what you've claimed. I told you to close `pw` and *not* the socket. Closing `pw` closes the socket.  If you closed the socket after `pw`, it would have worked. If you closed the socket before `pw`, neither the flush nor the close of `pw` could possibly have had any effect. *Ergo* if it didn't work, you closed the socket first. NB  Flush before close is redundant.